# How to fully localize Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, localization

I have a new Windows 10 Home, and it is installed in *German language* and I intend to change it to my native language (which is not English). According to [this](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10), I have to add the desired language and *apply it to welcome screen, system accounts, etc*.

It says: "*Reboot your computer and upon restart, you should see the new default language globally set through the operating system.*"

Well, it is mostly set...

I can see my Windows localized (my native is not English) but when I try to find something in the Start Menu (for example *Check for updates*), ***it can't find the search expression***. Instead, I have to enter *Nach Updates suchen* (also I see *Einstellungen für den Neztwerkproxy, Einstellungen für Netzbetrieb) but if I click those expression, nothing happens!*

How can I **fully localize** my Windows 10?

Comment: Since you can find only those German expression, it seems to me your Windows is fully localized. Maybe you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @FleetCommand Done, I clarified it. It is installed in German but I want it to be changed :)

Comment: Is your native language's Language Pack a full localization? Not all Microsoft language packs are full localizations.

Comment: @FleetCommand I can't tell. Where can I check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Using the following solution, I was able to remove the native language and now all the Start Menu items are working properly.

[Remove language from Windows 10 using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539292/remove-language-from-windows-10-using-powershell)

**OBSOLETE**

Well, according to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-mix-languages/10038898-278a-4ca0-b571-41de570381de?page=1) in the official Microsoft forum, it is a ***BUG*** that happens with the search items in Start Menu when using non-base languages.

*"After having tried everything, except reinstalling Windows, I have come to the conclusion that it's a bug. Microsoft has not full control over language settings in Windows 10, apparently.
Another issue, most likely relating to the same cause, is that Windows Search does not return any hits."*

The system can see the proper localized value, but shows the original language text (in this case German) and when you click it, it can't navigate to it as it is already localized in the background.

So it seems no matter what I do, I can't fix it otherwise but reinstalling Windows (that is so 2000...)

Let's see if Creators Update will help with that in April of 2017...

Comment: Please quote the relevant information.